# Как передать файлы с сервера на клиент? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, express

Как с использованием ExpressJS передать статические файлы на клиент? Такие файлы как скрипты и стили.
Сервер на NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // назначаешь публичную папку
```

суешь в папку *public* - стили и скрипты(**не** .html файлы), потом их подключаешь как будто они рядом лежат, например:

```html
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```